# Why are basic shapes in Inkscape not vector paths?

Tags: inkscape, vector

I am working with Inkscape and vector graphics. My dilemma is the following:

I start by assuming that any vector object/image is essentially a vector path (straight or curved) with anchors (nodes) and handles to change the edges between the nodes. Curved paths are called Bezier curves, straight paths aren't. That said, a simple rectangle created in Inkscape is a called a basic shape and it can only be rescaled (its sides cannot be modified unless we use the command Object to path to convert it to a vector path).
But isn't the rectangle (or any basic shape) also a vector object and, as such, shouldn't it be vector path with anchors and handles that we can tweak? Isn't everything we create in Inkscape (circle, rectangle, etc.), basic shapes included, a vector object which is equivalent to being a vector path?

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, your assumption is wrong. Sorry.  Inkscape is not just a vector image editor, it's an SVG editor. SVGs are a kind of XML, basically just code.

Some SVG shapes are not actually paths - they're SVG elements like this:

```
<rect x="21.1" y="54.6" width="34.3" height="18.6"/>
<circle cx="38.2" cy="103" r="12.9"/>
<ellipse cx="38.2" cy="142" rx="16.4" ry="7.5"/>
```

As you already said, you can of course turn these into paths if you want. In Inkscape select a shape and do Path > Object to Path.  This will convert the shapes into actual vector paths, something like this:

```
<path
       id="rect846"
       d="m 21.061296,54.616585 h 34.26923 v 18.5625 h -34.26923 z" />
<path
       id="path870"
       d="M 51.046873,103.16467 A 12.850962,12.850962 0 0 1 38.195911,116.01563 12.850962,12.850962 0 0 1 25.34495,103.16467 12.850962,12.850962 0 0 1 38.195911,90.313711 12.850962,12.850962 0 0 1 51.046873,103.16467 Z" />
<path
       id="path872"
       d="m 54.616585,141.71754 a 16.420673,7.4963942 0 0 1 -16.420674,7.4964 16.420673,7.4963942 0 0 1 -16.420673,-7.4964 16.420673,7.4963942 0 0 1 16.420673,-7.49639 16.420673,7.4963942 0 0 1 16.420674,7.49639 z" />
```

As you can see, there are situations where an SVG element is preferrable. It can for example help reduce the file size of SVGs, also SVG elements are editable in the sense that you can easily change their parameters, something that's not so easy if you just have paths.

There are also other benefits to leaving shapes as shapes in Inkscape rather than converting to paths. Circles can be edited as segments, and polygons and stars can be adjusted with controls,  and rectangles have adjustable curved corners, etc. If you convert these to paths, these functions are no longer possible.

Example

[image]

Comment: All makes more sense now to look at a basic shape as a SVG element in Inkscape. I even read that HTML files are a kind XML too even if I thought that XML came after HTML. Both XML and HTML are text files with instructions....

Comment: @BrettCooper Yes. HTML and SVG are both kinds of XML.  Remember also that SVGs can be created and edited manually in a text editor.  Inkscape is basically a WYSIWYG SVG editor. Cool, eh?

Comment: @BrettCooper - another thing to be aware of, if you want to get into this further, is that Inkscape's native SVG format also contains additional Inkscape-specific XML which is not part of the SVG standard as such.  This enables much of the functionality shown in the screen capture above. When exporting as plain SVG or optimised SVG, some of this native Inkscape functionality can be lost. Some shapes may be converted to paths for example, so it's always important to save your work as a native Inkscape SVG if you want to edit it later.

Comment: Very cool and clarifying, thanks. I am learning about XML which seems to be getting replaced by JSON, at least I read. It is a neutral language to transfer data between machines in the sense that machines with different software architectures can exchange the data and have the tools to parse that data into their own understandable language. XML, HTML, doc files are all text-files. I guess the difference is their type of metadata and encoding and the commonality is that they can all be opened and modified with a text editor.

Comment: @BrettCooper I've given you some upvotes to help with your rep score.  Forgot to say welcome to GDSE by the way!! Keep asking! Keep contributing!!

Comment: @BillyKerr i would argue that this editability is of very limited value. It woud be better if svg didnt have them,

Comment: The star example, btw., is saved as a vector path. It's only a star to Inkscape due to its metadata.

Comment: @Moini - I know. I already alluded to that in one of my comments where I called it Inkscape-specific XML, which is used for some of the functionality.  I was trying not to go deep into that in my answer, so as keep it simple.

Comment: @BrettCooper no, HTML isn't XML. They're just related by common descent from SGML. There was something called XHTML which was HTML as a subset of XML, but it's been effectively dead for ~10 years.

Comment: @BrettCooper I dont think XML is replaced by json as such. But cartainly any tagging language may do your job if you dont need any existing ecosystem services.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that Bézier curves can't do exact circles - they can get pretty close, but not perfect.

Comment: @BrettCooper Might be a bit deep down the historical rabbit hole, but HTML 4 was valid SGML (and XHTML was valid XML), but they gave up on that with HTML 5 because HTML 4 didn’t describe what designers were writing or what browsers were parsing very well (and in that regard XHTML was even worse). As for JSON, XML was used for a lot of things where it was complete overkill, and JSON is much more compact, easy to write, easy to read, easy to parse format that is better suited to those needs. For things that actually leverage the greater detail possible in XML, JSON is much less desirable.

Comment: @hobbs - yeah, I should have said HTML and SVG are both markup languages. My mistake.